# onchange in dropdown triggers function but no change in three.js output

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to make the page display either a green or a brown floor using three.js depending on the selection from a drop down list. However, I see that the floor images do not change although control does go to the function.

JS fiddle [here](https://jsbin.com/bapenewuzi/edit?html,css,js,console,output) (I could not upload images though)

The code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Floor change</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script>

    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var container;

    //controls
    var controls;

    //html elements
    var colorselection = "green";

    function init() {
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        SCREEN_WIDTH-=200;
//        SCREEN_HEIGHT -= 100;

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render, sets the background color and the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 30;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // attach div element to variable to contain the renderer
        container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );

        // attach renderer to the container div
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    }

    function floor()
    {
        ///////////
        // FLOOR //
        ///////////

        if(colorselection == "green")
            var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'green.jpg' );
        else if(colorselection == "brown")/*go with 2 for now*/
            var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'brown.png' );
        floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        floorTexture.repeat.set( 20, 20 );
        // DoubleSide: render texture on both sides of mesh
        var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(110, 110, 1, 1);
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
        floor.position.y = -0.5;
        floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        scene.add(floor);

        animate();
    }

    //scheduler loop
    function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera)
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }

    function myfunction()
    {
        colorselection = document.getElementById("mydropdownlist").value;
        console.log("clicked on '"+ colorselection + "'")
        floor();
    }

    // calls the init function when the window is done loading.
    window.onload = init;
</script>
<body>
<script src="js/Three.js"></script>

<div id="ThreeJS" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>

<select id="mydropdownlist" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="brown">brown</option>
</select>
</body>

<style>
    #mydropdownlist
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:1200px;
        top:20px
    }
</style>

</html>
```

I have uploaded the images brown.png and green.jpg used above.

[image: brown.png]
[image: green.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code to a local .html file, put it in the example directory for 3js, stuck the pictures there, and then updated the path to three.js to the default one

> src="../build/Three.js"

and ran it in chrome.  It worked, the floor colors changed when i used the drop-down. It also works in firefox.

I do see a problem however. You add the new floor mesh each time to the scene, but do not remove the old one. I expect to see a scene.remove(floor) before you make a new one so you dont get a bunch piled up in the scene.  I also noticed that you have a function called floor and a variable called floor which can cause confusion.

Also, if you are using chrome, you need to use  --disable-web-security as a command-line switch if you want to see the textures when the files are on your local drive instead of a web-server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Floor change</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script>

    // global variables
    var renderer;
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var container;


 var floormesh=null; 
    //controls
    var controls;

    //html elements
    var colorselection = "green";

    function init() {
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        SCREEN_WIDTH-=200;
//        SCREEN_HEIGHT -= 100;

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render, sets the background color and the size
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 30;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // attach div element to variable to contain the renderer
        container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );

        // attach renderer to the container div
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    }
    function floor()
    {
        ///////////
        // FLOOR //
        ///////////

        if(colorselection == "green")
            var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'green.jpg' );
        else if(colorselection == "brown")/*go with 2 for now*/
            var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'brown.png' );
        floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        floorTexture.repeat.set( 20, 20 );
        // DoubleSide: render texture on both sides of mesh
        var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(110, 110, 1, 1);
if(floormesh)
    scene.remove(floormesh);

        floormesh = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
        floormesh.position.y = -0.5;
        floormesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        scene.add(floormesh);

        animate();
    }

    //scheduler loop
    function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera)
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }

    function myfunction()
    {
        colorselection = document.getElementById("mydropdownlist").value;
        console.log("clicked on '"+ colorselection + "'")
        floor();
    }

    // calls the init function when the window is done loading.
    window.onload = init;
</script>
<body>
<script src="../build/Three.js"></script>

<div id="ThreeJS" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>

<select id="mydropdownlist" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="brown">brown</option>
</select>
</body>

<style>
    #mydropdownlist
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:1200px;
        top:20px
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please pass me a js fiddle link to the working file. I'm surprised, the same does not work for me.

Comment: I have no idea how to use jsfiddle.  i will edit my post. there, its in there.  remember to look at the debug console output to see if you are getting an error. if it is cross-domain, its because you need to set the browser to use local files

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think if(floormesh)
        floor.position.y = -0.5;      scene.remove(floormesh); was the touch.